# Cholesky factor when adding a row and column to already factorized matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I have a positive deifnite, symmetrical, $N\times N$ real matrix $A$ which has 1's on the diagonal and all off-diagonal elements positive and $<1$. Let $A=LL^t$ be the Cholesky decomposition of $A$. Suppose now that I extend $A$ as follows:
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} A & a \\ a^t & 1 \end{array} \right)$$
where $a$ is a $N\times1$ real vector with positive elements $<1$. Thus the extended matrix has the same structure as the original matrix $A$. I would like to prove that the Cholesky factor of the extended matrix has the form
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} L & 0 \\ c^t & d \end{array} \right)$$
where $L$ is, again, the Cholesky factor of $A$, $c$ an appropriate $N\times 1$ real vector, and $d$ an appropriate scalar, positive or 0.

By definition of Cholesky factor, the following should hold:
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} A & a \\ a^t & 1 \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{cc} L & 0 \\ c^t & d \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{cc} L^t & c \\ 0 & d \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{cc} LL^t & Lc \\ L^tc^t & c^t c + d^2 \end{array} \right)$$
where I just carried out the matrix product. This is promising, and means that we have to prove that we can choose $c$ and $d$ so that these two statements hold:
$$a=Lc$$
$$1=c^tc+d^2$$
The first is easy because $L$ is invertible:
$$c=L^{-1}a$$
Then second equation becomes
$$1=a^t(L^{-1})^tL^{-1}a+d^2$$
or
$$1=a^tA^{-1}a+d^2$$
or
$$d=\sqrt{1 - a^tA^{-1}a }$$
which gives a real $d$ so long as $a^t A^{-1} a<1$, but I am not sure one can prove this. If that helps, the entries of $A$ and inner products of unit vectors. I have not been able to find numerical counterexamples, but the elements of $a$ are not necessarily small and in the worst case its norm is close to $N$. Is there something about the norm of $A^{-1}$ or of $L^-1$ that can help me out here?

Thanks,
Stefano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work, you should explicitly assume that $a^tA^{-1}a<1$; otherwise, the bordered matrix 
$$
B:=\begin{bmatrix}A & a\\a^t & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
would not be positive definite anymore (and thus the Cholesky factorization would not exist).

The simplest way to see it is to see this is to realize that
$$
XBX^t=\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&1-a^tA^{-1}a\end{bmatrix}=:C,
\quad
X:=\begin{bmatrix}I & 0 \\ -a^TA^{-1} & 1\end{bmatrix},
$$
that is (from the Sylvester's inertia theorem), the matrix $B$ has the same inertia as the matrix $C$. Consequently, the matrix $C$ has $N$ positive eigenvalues (since $A$ is SPD) and one eigenvalue with the same sign as that of $1-a^tA^{-1}a$.

Note that $a^tA^{-1}a<1$ is the *necessary* and sufficient condition for $B$ being SPD.

Comment: That is splendid, especially the last line --- I knew that the $B$ matrix (your notation) was positive semi-definite but I was not making any use of this. But what is the matrix $X$? (Also, I assume that you mean $a^tA^{-1}a<1$ in your first line, rather than $a^tAa<1$.)

Comment: @Stefano Glad you like it :) Actually, $B$ is semidefinite if $a^tA^{-1}a\leq 0$; $B$ is SPSD singular iff $a^tA^{-1}a=0$. If $a^TA^{-1}a>1$, $B$ is indefinite (with one negative eigenvalue).

Comment: Great. I edited the comment to ask what $X$ is, it did not appear in my original post.

Comment: Ooops. Sorry I "left" its definition for later but then forgot to define it. Making edit.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I guess you meant to write $XBX^t$ rather than $XAX^t$, right?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I guess I need more coffee.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17595/discussion-between-stefano-and-algebraic-pavel).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Hi! Note $\mathbf{A}$ is positive definite and hence a gram matrix of linearly independent vectors. What if i also want the extended matrix to be positive definite, i.e., under what conditions on $\mathbf{a}$ the extended matrix has unique cholesky factorization.

Comment: @VinayakAbrol Hi. How is your question different from the one asked by OP and answered above? Provided that $A$ is SPD, the augmented matrix ($B$ in the answer) is SPD if and only if $a^tA^{-1}a<1$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel I want the extended matrix to be PD not SPD. Only in PD case we have a unique Cholesky decomposition i.e., $B$ is the gram matrix of linearly independent vectors. (Am i missing something here?)

Comment: @VinayakAbrol SPD means *symmetric positive definite* here (not semidefinite, if that is what puzzles you).

Answer (score 1):

In general it does not work, because $a^tA^{-1}a$ can be bigger than 1.

For example. If $A$ is symmetric positive definite with all entries bigger than $0$ and the entries in the diagonal equal to 1 then we can prove that there are elements in the diagonal of $A^{-1}$ bigger than 1. Suppose the first element in the diagonal of $A^{-1}$ is bigger than 1, then if $a=(1-\epsilon,\epsilon,\ldots,\epsilon)$ and $\epsilon>0$ really small then $a^tA^{-1}a$ is very close to $e_1^tA^{-1}e_1>1$, where $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)$.

Suppose $A$ is symmetric positive definite with all entries bigger than $0$ and the entries in the diagonal equal to 1. By [Fiedler's inequality](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=J-u2t23tkG4C&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=fiedler's%20inequality&source=bl&ots=MAf34ul9b6&sig=4g7YJxBjIo90J2u0NFo1kucfoQA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dZT2U_2GPIjLsATj3YH4Cg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=fiedler's%20inequality&f=false) $A\circ A^{-1}-Id$ is positive semidefinite, where $\circ$ is the [Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).

Since the elements in the diagonal of $A$ are 1 then the elements in the diagonal of  $A^{-1}$ must be greater or equal to 1. If they are all equal to 1 then the diagonal of $A\circ A^{-1}-Id$ contains only zeros and the $trace(A\circ A^{-1}-Id)=0$, but this implies $A\circ A^{-1}-Id=0$, since it is positive semidefinite. Thus, $A\circ A^{-1}=Id$. Since all the off-diagonal elements of $A$ are not zero, it implies that all off-diagonal elements of $A^{-1}$ are zero. Thus, $A^{-1}=Id$ and $A=Id$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks you for the counterexample. It turns out, though, that we were not using the fact that the extended matrix is known to be positive semi-definite, which guarantees $a^t A^{-1}a<1$, see @algebraic-pavel's answer.