# Proving positive definiteness of matrix $a_{ij}=\frac{2x_ix_j}{x_i + x_j}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

I'm trying to prove that the matrix with entries $\left\{\frac{2x_ix_j}{x_i + x_j}\right\}_{ij}$ is positive definite for all n, where n is the number of rows/columns.

I was able to prove it for the 2x2 case by showing the determinant is always positive. However, once I extend it to the 3x3 case I run into trouble. I found a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955874/cholesky-factor-when-adding-a-row-and-column-to-already-factorized-matrix)
whose chosen answer gave a condition for positive definiteness of the extended matrix, and after evaluating the condition and maximizing it via software, the inequality turned out to hold indeed, but I just can't show it.

Furthermore, it would be way more complicated when I go to 4x4 and higher. I think I should somehow use induction here to show it for all n, but I think I'm missing something. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Actually the mistake is mine, turns out there are indeed no squares in the denominator, so it turns out user141614's first answer is what I really needed. Thanks a lot! Should I just accept this answer, or should it be changed back to his first answer then I accept it?

Comment: $\{x_i\}$ are arbitrary?

Comment: Yes, I think this still forces all entries to be between -1 and 1.

Comment: $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ should be positive and distinct.

Comment: @user141614 actually they can be negative, no? and distinctness is only required for strictly positive definiteness, am i right?

Comment: First I missed the squares in the denominator. So $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ can be negative, but the matrix is positive definite only if $|x_1|,...,|x_n|$ are distinct.

Answer (score 10):

(Update: Some fixes have been added because I solved the problem with $a_{ij}=\frac{2x_ix_j}{x_i+x_j}$ instead of $a_{ij}=\frac{2x_ix_j}{x_i^2+x_j^2}$. Thanks to Paata Ivanisvili for his comment.)

The trick is writing the expression $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ as an integral.

For every nonzero vector $(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ of reals,
$$
(u_1,\ldots,u_n) \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & \dots & a_{nn} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} u_1\\ \vdots \\ u_n\end{pmatrix} =
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} u_i u_j =
$$
$$
=2 \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n u_i u_j x_i x_j \frac1{x_i^2+x_j^2} =
2\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n u_i u_j x_i x_j \int_{t=0}^\infty 
\exp \Big(-(x_i^2+x_j^2)t\Big) \mathrm{d}t =
$$
$$
=2\int_{t=0}^\infty 
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i x_i \exp\big(-{x_i^2}t\big)\right)
\left(\sum_{j=1}^n u_j x_j \exp\big(-{x_j^2}t\big)\right)
\mathrm{d}t =
$$
$$
=2\int_{t=0}^\infty 
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i x_i \exp\big(-{x_i^2t}\big)\right)^2
\mathrm{d}t \ge 0.
$$
If $|x_1|,\ldots,|x_n|$ are distinct and nonzero then the last integrand cannot be constant zero: for large $t$ the minimal $|x_i|$ with $u_i\ne0$ determines the magnitude order. So the integral is strictly positive.

If there are equal values among $|x_1|,\ldots,|x_n|$ then the integral may vanish. Accordingly, the corresponding rows of the matrix are equal or the negative of each other, so the matrix is only positive semidefinite.

---

You can find many variants of this inequality. See 
[problem A.477. of the KöMaL magazine](http://www.komal.hu/verseny/feladat.cgi?a=feladat&f=A447&l=en).

The entry $a_{ij}$ can be replaced by $\left(\frac{2x_ix_j}{x_i+x_j}\right)^c$ with an arbitrary fixed positive $c$; see
[problem A.493. of KöMaL](http://www.komal.hu/verseny/feladat.cgi?a=feladat&f=A493&l=en).

Comment: Actually the matrix is $\frac{2x_{i} x_{j}}{x^{2}_{i}+x^{2}_{j}}$ so there is a sum of the squares in the denominator. But clearly positivity of the matrix $\frac{2x_{i} x_{j}}{x^{2}_{i}+x^{2}_{j}}$ follows from the positivity of $\frac{1}{x^{2}_{i}+x^{2}_{j}}$ (because you can conjugate with diagonal matrix). And positivity of the last matrix  follows from your reasoning $\frac{1}{x_{i}^{2}+x_{j}^{2}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-sx_{i}^{2}}e^{-sx_{j}^{2}}ds$

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Updated.

Comment: Shouldn't the sum read $2 \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n u_i u_j x_i^{-1} x_j^{-1} \frac1{\frac1{x_i^2}+\frac1{x_j^2}}$?

Comment: OK, one more mistake to fix. :-)