# Proving the matrix is positive semidefintie through integrals

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, matrices, inequality, positive-semidefinite

I have come across quite a lot of proofs to show that a matrix is positive semidefinite through integrals. Examples are

[Showing that $(A_{ij})=\left(\frac1{1+x_i+x_j}\right)$ is positive semidefinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313249/showing-that-a-ij-left-frac11x-ix-j-right-is-positive-semidefinite?rq=1)

[Proving positive definiteness of matrix $a_{ij}=\frac{2x_ix_j}{x_i + x_j}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631439/proving-positive-definiteness-of-matrix-a-ij-frac2x-ix-jx-i-x-j)

[Prove positive definiteness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783164/prove-positive-definiteness?noredirect=1&lq=1)

It seems like, a common trait is writing the matrix entries as an integral of a dot product $M_{ij}  = \int_a^b  F_i(x) F_j(x) g(x) dx$. Then one can kind of think of this matrix as $M = B^T B$. Here $B$ has "infinite rows" as instead of summation we are doing integration, but a lot of ideas can be borrowed.

Is my understanding correct? Is there a name for this kind of approach and matrix? Is there a trick to find the $F_i, F_j$?

Comment: I'm not sure about the infinite matrix. I would think of this more akin to the fact that $\sum_i B_i^T B_i$ is positive semidefinite as each $B_i^T B_i$ is positive semidefinite, except you replace the sum with an integral.

Comment: [The answer to the first question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/313253/81360) that the integral will give you a positive semidefinite matrix